# IDWriteFactory не все ссылки сбрасываются при вызове Release

Tags: c++, directx

В классе создается 1 экземпляр `IDWriteFactory` и при уничтожении класса естественно освобождается вызовом метода `Release()`.
Начал отладку уничтожения ресурсов класса и заметил, все интерфейсы `DirectX` освободились нормально, а вот `IDWriteFactory` вернул 1, т.е. на него осталась 1 ссылка. На самом деле это происходит даже в том случае когда на интерфейс нет ссылок совсем, т.е. интерфейс был создан но, не использовался.

Почему такое происходит и как бороться?

Код конструктора:

```
static D2D1_POINT_2F dpi = { 0, 0 };

if (!m_render_window_handle_ || IsWindow(m_render_window_handle_) != TRUE)
{
    if (UpdateWindow(m_render_window_handle_) == TRUE)
    {
        if (IsWindow(m_render_window_handle_) != TRUE)
        {
            std::exception("Invalid Window Handle! You cannot continue to create the graphics renderer.");
        }
        const LONG l_styles = GetWindowLong(m_render_window_handle_, GWL_STYLE);
        if (l_styles & WS_MINIMIZE)
        {
            ShowWindow(m_render_window_handle_, SW_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    std::exception("Invalid Window Handle! You cannot continue to create the graphics renderer.");
}

marioka_render_factory_options factory_options;
memset(&factory_options, 0, sizeof factory_options);
factory_options.debugLevel =
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION;
#else
    D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE;
#endif;

HRESULT result = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_render_factory_);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    throw std::exception("Failed to create Direct2D Factory");
}

m_render_factory_->GetDesktopDpi(&dpi.x, &dpi.y);

marioka_rect rc;
GetClientRect(m_render_window_handle_, &rc);
const marioka_size_u size = SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

marioka_render_target_properties render_target_properties;
memset(&render_target_properties, 0, sizeof render_target_properties);
render_target_properties.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE;
render_target_properties.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_UNKNOWN;
render_target_properties.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
render_target_properties.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;
render_target_properties.minLevel = D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_9;
render_target_properties.dpiX = dpi.x;
render_target_properties.dpiY = dpi.y;

marioka_hwnd_render_target_properties hwnd_render_target_properties;
memset(&hwnd_render_target_properties, 0, sizeof hwnd_render_target_properties);
hwnd_render_target_properties.hwnd = m_render_window_handle_;
hwnd_render_target_properties.pixelSize = size;
hwnd_render_target_properties.presentOptions = D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_IMMEDIATELY;

result = m_render_factory_->CreateHwndRenderTarget(&render_target_properties, &hwnd_render_target_properties,
                                                   &m_render_target_);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    m_render_factory_->Release();
    m_render_factory_ = nullptr;
    throw std::exception("Failed to create RenderTarget");
}

m_render_target_->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Identity());
m_render_target_->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE);
m_render_target_->SetTextAntialiasMode(D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE_CLEARTYPE);

result = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(m_write_factory_), reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&m_write_factory_));

if(result != S_OK)
{
    m_render_target_->Release();
    m_render_target_ = nullptr;
    m_render_factory_->Release();
    m_render_factory_ = nullptr;

    throw std::exception("Failed to create IDWriteFactory");
}
```

Код деструктора:

```
UINT result = m_render_target_->Release();
m_render_target_ = nullptr;

result = m_write_factory_->Release();
m_write_factory_ = nullptr;

result = m_render_factory_->Release();
m_render_factory_ = nullptr;

m_instances_map_.erase(m_render_window_);

m_render_window_ = nullptr;
m_render_window_handle_ = nullptr;
```

[image: render_target_]
[image: render_write_]
[image: render_factory_]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создавая фабрику с флагом `DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED` будет еще инициализироваться некоторый кэширующий объект. При этом при выходе их приложения он самоликвидируется и никакой утечки тут не происходит. Этого поведения можно избежать передав флаг `DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED`.